# Reference Request - Resources about Problems for College Math Quiz-bowl Competitions

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, contest-math

The purpose of this post is to ask if there are any existing resources regarding college-level math quiz bowls (or quiz bowl-like competitions) in which problems could be taken and used for such events?

For context, I am a part of a student math club at my college, and we're looking to create a math quiz bowl in order to bolster the general student body's interest in math, and hopefully lead to fundraising opportunities for the clubs in the department (which is suffering to due to budget cuts) to then hopefully lead to more similar events.

We have tried to search for the last few weeks for sets of problems online that have been tried and tested for the quiz bowl format (or in a similar) in which teams of five students have ten seconds to buzz in an answer per question, but we couldn't find any resource on both how to structure these kinds of events or for problems that could fit in the mentioned constraints.

The aim is to keep the math subjects both at an undergrad level and diverse between theory and applied to accommodate the wide range of backgrounds of students in the department.

Thus, any provided resources will aid immensely and will come with many thanks!

Comment: You might have better luck asking this on the [Math Educators](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/) site. I won't guarantee it, though.